# r. mapcalc error in grass gis 7

Tags: grass-7.0

After upgrading to 7.0.4, I could not execute r.mapcalc perfectly, there is a problem :

syntax error, unexpected INTEGER, expecting VARNAME or NAME
Parse error
ERROR: parse error
ERROR: An error occurred while running r.mapcalc

It happened when i try to mosaic some images, all the required parameters were already set up correctly.

Anyone have a clue ?